# Wordpress only users can see

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I have a subdomain,I want to only users can see my site.
when someone logged in to my site,Let the user see the login screen.
How I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution will be to use the following plugin (Registered Users Only): https://wordpress.org/plugins/registered-users-only/

Comment: Have you activated it tho? Would be great to see the settings

Comment: Yes, it works. t didn't work because of the security plugin. thanks for your help